# Prevent script from re-executing action on page refresh

Tags: php, shopping-cart

I am building my own **php cart** for the past week and I got stuck in some issues.

I managed to add new items in the cart, and the URL looks like below.

```
http://blah-blah.com/order/index.php?action=add&id=84
```

The question is simple: How can I prevent from adding the same item again in the cart
if someone refreshes the page? Cause now every time someone refreshes the page, it changes the quantity to +1 for the specific item..

Also, after moving to the checkout page, if they press the back button in the browser, AGAIN the quantity will change  to +1;

Any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yea. Have them *set*, rather than *increment* the quantity.

Also, you'd usually use `POST` (not `GET`) requests for this sort of action. Browsers know this and cunningly ask the user whether they want to re-submit `POST` data.

The cleanest approach for your user may be to do the whole thing with AJAX. If they go "back", they'll just go back to the last page they visited without trouble. This would be equivalent to how comments on Stack Overflow are submitted: you cannot go "back" to your submission step and end up writing duplicate comments.

Comment: Yeah I thought of using POST instead, but I was not sure if it was a better solution than using GET. Alternatively, I can still use the GET option and add a new item only if it is not already in the cart. Now, the users can change the quantity by enter the quantity themselves and press the update btn that I added. How does it sound? Is it better than the POST method?

Comment: @george: `POST` is _designed_ for this sort of thing. `GET` is not. The hint is in the name, really.

Comment: No, it isn't. GET's should not change anything, be cachable & repeatable:[_"In particular, the convention has been established that the GET and HEAD methods SHOULD NOT have the significance of taking an action other than retrieval. These methods ought to be considered "safe"."_](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

Comment: @Tomalak: ah, yeah, the _"no it isn't"_ clearly was for @george, not you, indeed :)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest following steps to avoid multiple submission and back button issues:

1. As suggested above you should use POST method to submit your form instead of GET.
2. Prevent multiple form submission from the same session as described here:    http://phpsense.com/php/prevent-duplicate-form-submission.html
3. After you're done with processing the POST request you should redirect to a **confirmation URI** OR better to the same URI as follows:

   // redirect after processing the POST request
   header("Location: " . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
   exit;

Answer (score 0):

As said by Tomalak it's better to use POST datas for thoose kind of action.
An other point you can use in conjunction with POST datas is to respond to the user with a redirect header then even if he try to refresh or go back the data won't be processed again.

basic example:

```
<?php
if( !empty($_POST) ){
  // do stuff with POST datas then
  header("location: mypage.php\n");
  exit;
}
```

Comment: I think you example is a little too basic ;)

Comment: oups forgot code formatting so didn't displayed thank's for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<?php
header("Location: http://www.example.com/"); /* Redirect browser */
```

To redirect your user to the previous page? Pressing refresh or the back/forward buttons will not load the add page again.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is closed, But i have an alternative that I thought up for this exact problem.

The idea is to create a hash of $_POST data before and after.  For this example i used md5, but you can use whatever algorithm you want:

```
$postHash = md5(serialize($_POST).date("dMY",time()));
if(!isset($_SESSION['post'])) $_SESSION['post']="Not yet set.";
```

Then all your processing code that would normally go at the top of the page you simply put into the following IF:

```
    if($_SESSION['post']!=$postHash) {
     // Perform actions
    } else {
  echo "Cannot post duplicate data";
}
```

Then, at the bottom of the page (or after processing has complete, and any database calls have been actioned):

```
$_SESSION['post'] = md5(serialize($_POST).date("dMY",time()));
```

There are still a few problems but it seems to work okay. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I don't have a coding solution for you but rather a **logical solution** to this problem give it a try it might help you, it helped me

I faced the same problem where I used the **"ShoppingCart?AddToCart=1&....."** in my URL(GET Variable) as a way of knowing that the user wants to add products to the cart and every time I refreshed the page the same product got added again and again

My way of working when I received the **AddToCart Request** was to **first** execute a method that will **add** the product to cart **and then** execute another method that will **display** the contents of the cart **(THIS WAS THE PROBLEM RIGHT HERE)**

I changed the logic a bit

Now whenever I receive the same **AddToCart Request** I execute the **same first method** to add the contents to the cart

**BUT**

Now rather than executing the second method to display the content of the cart I use the header("Location: ShoppingCart?ViewCart=1")

This means that after executing the first method which add the content to the cart I make a **ViewCart Request** to my Shopping Cart page, now every time I make a **AddToCart Request** it properly adds the contents to the cart and after that whenever I try to **refresh the page** to **try to replicate the AddToCart Request** I always end up with **ViewCart Request** and the Page simply shows the Cart contents and not add any futher contents to the cart

The trick over here is that every time I receive the **"ShoppingCart?AddToCart=1&....."** I execute the Add function and the header function in such a way that I end up with displaying **"ShoppingCart?ViewCart=1"** in the URL rather than the original **"ShoppingCart?AddToCart=1&....."**

Now even if some tries to refresh the page or comes back to the page using Back Button in the browser they always end making a **"ShoppingCart?ViewCart=1"** Request, they never see the **"ShoppingCart?AddToCart=1&....."** in the URL

like I said I don't have a Coding Solution but rather a Logical Solution

Hope this helps