# insert data into the database once and not come several times

Tags: php

this is how I work to make a comment system since,

and this is how I use header to "reload" the page to only while lying info into the database.

when I sent info into the database and I click f5 then throw it into the database again. So like it is spam.

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO fms_kommentarforum (getid, brugerid, kommentar) VALUES (?, ?, ?)')) { 
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $getid, $brugerid, $kommentar);
$getid = $_GET['id']; 
$brugerid = $_SESSION["id"];
$kommentar = $_POST["beskedinfo"];
$stmt->execute();

   //reload the page again
   ob_start();
   header("Location: http://www.blabla.dk/forum/" . $_GET["id"] . "/" . $_GET["url"] . "/");
   ob_end_flush();

$stmt->close();
}
```

Addition the url to look like some out here; **blabla.com/forum/1/test---ae-oe-aa-aa/#**
that's when I sent info into the database once

I would like that # does not come on when it was.

and in the form I have written **action="#"**

Comment: so you want to reload the page to send to a database, but specifically not have items sent to a database on page reload. something about that isnt right...

Answer (score 0):

you could redirect the customer to the same uri with the 303 HTTP Status code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303

so the client can hit F5 without sending the post request again.

```
header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: http://example/post");
```

Comment: It does not work, send it remains in the database even though I click f5

Comment: hm, i guess i didnt catch your problem. you want to remove the database entry upon page reload? sorry, i dont get your problem.

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

A trick I've seen is basically add a random number to the GET/POST data and remember them when you do an update.  If you get a second update request using a previously-seen random number, you know it's come from an `F5` and skip the update.

EDIT: See: for example: [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6267034/prevent-script-from-re-executing-action-on-page-refresh) and [this web-page](http://phpsense.com/2006/prevent-duplicate-form-submission/).

Comment: I do not quite understand what you mean?

Comment: I'll try and dig up a reference, but basically, wherever you are generating the original URL that triggers the database update (perhaps from a "<form action=...>" page) you add as one of the form-data elements a random (or possibly incrementing) number.  When you process that URL, you test to see if the random/incrementing number has been seen before.  If so, you know you are seeing it as a result of a page-refresh.  If it's the first time you've seen that number, then you can do the database update.